# prestashop 1.7 update order custom field using webservice

Tags: web-services, updates, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on Prestashop 1.7.7.4. I've created a custom boolean field on ps_orders table and overridden Order model definition and webserviceParameters to add such field.

Now when I GET an order through webservice I fetch the field and I can use it as a filter.
Unfortunately I can't PUT such field through webservice. I noticed that such issue was already reported on prestashop issue tracker but it was closed.

So I'm wondering if anyone could address me to the solution or at least to a way to look into the right code to find the problem.

Thanks in advance for your kind answers.

Comment: Why don't you just create a standalone PHP file where you can do all the DB querys you want?

Comment: because I'd prefer to take advantage of built-in security features.